# Handling NaN entries in a dataframe created from CSV

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, types, nan

I am trying to compare two dataframes. The first dataframe is created from a dictionary. In places the values may be empty, like so:

```
'Room #': ''
```

The second dataframe is created from the corresponding exported csv. Where this key value is created in the dataframe has a NaN.

My comparison is using the

```
df.equals()
```

method

because there are the NaN items in the second dataframe, this is (correctly) returning a false.

What is the best method, please, of changing the NaN values to an appropriate type for comparison to those in the dictionary dataframe? Or otherwise disregarding the no entry/NaN key:values?
(I read that fillna is deprecated).

Comment: [`pandas.DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) is **not** deprecated.

Comment: Some arguments (options) for [`fillna` are deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html); not the whole function. So use `fillna`, probably with an empty string for value.

Comment: Use the option keep_default_na=False: df = pd.read_csv('toto.csv', index_col=0, dtype=object, keep_default_na=False)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) states, in not the most clear way, that `method="backfill"` is deprecated (use `method="bfill"` instead).

This works if you prefer `''` over `NaN`.

```py
df_read = pd.read_csv('...').fillna('')
is_eq = df_original.equals(df_read)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for my purposes. Agreed, maybe not the clearest. (Or at least, if I see deprecated, that's my take away)